# AWS Load Balancer and ECS container on different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

We have a containerized Webapp running on ECS Fargate in a Private Subnet of a VPC. This Private Subnet is connected to a Transit Gateway which allows connectivity to an on-premises network. We would like to make the solution secure by having the Public Load Balancer that Cloudfront can connect to, on a public subnet in a different VPC.

Currently, we have the Application Load Balancer (ALB) in a public subnet within the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) as the Elastic Container Service (ECS) container, which is running in a private subnet within the same VPC.

Is it possible to connect an ALB located in a public subnet in VPC A to an ECS container running in a private subnet in VPC B?

Comment: "We would like to make the solution secure by having the Public Load Balancer that Cloudfront can connect to, on a public subnet in a different VPC" I can think of some reasons to do this but this alone doesn't necessarily add security.

Answer (score 0):

it might not answer your question but i faced some similar problem before and here is how we solve it:
We put a public load balancer in a vpc, and we redirected all the traffic to a proxy in the same vpc, the proxy redirected the traffic to the internal load balancers of each vpc connected to the transit gateway according to the request url